# Запуск exe файла Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Добрый день!
Никак не могу разобраться как запустить внешнюю программу на Visual C++. Все что находил в инете - не получается.

Мой код:

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace Microsoft::Win32;

[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    String^ InstallPath = nullptr;
    RegistryKey^ rk = nullptr;

    rk = Registry::LocalMachine->OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MCFR\\KozaDisk");

    if (rk != nullptr)
    {
        array<String^>^ name = rk->GetValueNames();

        for (int i = 0; i < name->Length; i++)
        {
            String^ value = rk->GetValue(name[i])->ToString();

            if (name[i] == "InstallPath") InstallPath = value;
        }
    }

    if (InstallPath != nullptr)
    {
        String^ AppPath = InstallPath + "Koza.exe";
        // запускаем приложение AppPath
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Install");
    }
}
```

В переменной String^ AppPath находится полный путь к приложению, которое надо запустить. Как мне это сделать?

Заранее спасибо!!

Comment: *"Как мне это сделать?"* -- Заглянуть в какой-нибудь справочник по функциям Windows?

Comment: CreateProcess можно еще использовать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это делается так:

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start(AppPath);
```

---

Обратите внимание, что вы пишете вовсе не на C++. Вы пишете на C++/CLI, расширении C++ для .NET. Это совсем другой язык.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!